# Sending Flash SMS in UCS2 (that is encoding) on smpp

Tags: network-programming, sms, gsm, network-protocols, smpp

In order to send a flash SMS on smpp protocol we use the data-coding field (ver. 3.4 or 5.0) inside the PDU. On the other hand, if we want to send a normal sms in any language we use the same field so as to support the extended characters in that language. So smpp protocol has added some optional fields, which are called TLV so as to support such a functionality. In gsm protocol there is no such a problem because they introduced 'message class' [see : 3GPP protocol](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=141) . So, to come back to *[smpp protocol](http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv50.pdf)*, they use the TLV `dest_addr_subunit` but is not clear how to use it so as to send a sms with ucs2. Can you give an example or a way to support that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Flash SMS, you set TLV DATA_CODING to 0x18 value.

Comment: This is ok for gsm protocol (air) but not for smpp protocol

Comment: Nope. This is a valid for SMPP protocol. DATA_CODING SMPP field is translated into TP-DCS GSM MAP protocol (which has subpart as message class 0-flash).
Perhaps your SMPP provider on SMSC has some translation or limitation - check with them. Also note, that some phone models has buggy software which doesnt show properly flash messages.
What is your result if you set 0x18 in SMPP DATA_CODING and send it over the air ?

Comment: Here is example for simple flash sms sent to SMPP and analyzed from the air: SMPP Protocol( ESM_CLASS:0 PROTOCOL_ID:0 PRIORITY_FLAG:0 DATA_CODING: 24) GSM protocol( TP-RP: 0 TP-UDHI: 0 TP-SRI: 1 TP-LP: 0 TP-MMS: 1 TP-MTI: 0 TP-PID: 0 TP-DCS: 24)

Comment: When send 0x18, it displays Flash sms with some Chinese inside and 0xF0 displays a flash sms with ok Latin but not extented chars

Comment: I think you are right to the fact that are some translation limitations

Comment: Also, according to smpp v. 5.0 or 3.4 value 0x18 is reserved (e.g. 00001111 - 10111111 are reserved)

Comment: Do you know which vendor is SMSC ? 
dest_addr_subunit tag is otherwise to tell, where phone will store the message (phone memory, simcard, etc), but its from the old days, now phones do it mostly by themselfs. Try to set it to 0x1 if it would work.

Comment: It creates a flash SMS with GSM 7 bit default alphabet encoding which means we have no encoding for extented chars

Comment: Then for sure, something has been made on ESME profile on SMSC you're attaching to. You should contact SMSC operator to check and change :) 

Can you post full SMPP parameters you are using (except mobile number of course)